# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I prepared below script to drop default value column.

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] 
ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] DROP DEFAULT;
```

But It has following error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the name of the default constraint, and drop the constraint by name:

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] DROP CONSTRAINT [constraint_name];
```

Comment: I need to use same script in multiple environments so I can't determine constraint  name as same for all environments

Comment: @BanuSharma Yes you can and you MUST. So your question now becomes "how do I find the name of a specific constraint". Time to read some documentation for [sys.default_constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-default-constraints-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @BanuSharma To further on SMor's comment, when creating a constraint (defaults are constraints), *always name them*. It is possible to create constraints without specifying the name explicitly, in which case a random name is assigned (random on each database instance). If the constraint has a random name, you will have to jump through more hoops to delete it (i.e. more scripting than simply the one statement I have in my answer).

Comment: @BanuSharma In short: create constraints with a name, so that you can use a simple script to delete any constraints by name.